# Cocoapods, private repo: how can add spec without pass the validation?

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I have some files that won't pass the validation only after I add them to the super project. (using pod file)
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a indicator of a bigger problem of how your projects are setup. But to bypass this for a private repo, copy your spec to the correct folder location in `~/.cocoapods/repos/your-repo` and commit it with git.